# Prevent page break after multicols star environment

Tags: multicol, starred-version

`multicols` environment of `multicol package` produces page break in starred version. How can we prevent this page break?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
    \begin{proof}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \begin{multicols*}{4}
                \item First
                \columnbreak
                \item Second
                \columnbreak
                \item Third
                \columnbreak
                \item Fourth
            \end{multicols*}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{proof}
Can you help me to stay in the same page?
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are putting the `multicols*` environment inside a nested list environment. Moving it out helps a bit, but not much. Really, I don't think you should be trying to use multiple columns here. It really doesn't make any sense. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: If you must use multicols, why can't you just use `\begin{multicols}{4}
  \begin{proof}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item First
      \item Second
      \item Third
      \item Fourth
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{proof}
\end{multicols}
Can you help me to stay in the same page?
` ?

Comment: @cfr This is just an illustrating example to show the issue! In my real work, each item is an answer to a small exercise of linear equation. To demonstrate a step by step solution, the answer is written downward. Since the width of solution content is too short, I decided to put them into four columns. Additionally, each solution length is not equal, I chose starred-version of `multicols`.

Comment: If you are using `\columnbreak`, why do you need the `*`? Anyway, I really wouldn't use multiple columns here.

Comment: @cfr Manually break columns in non-starred-version of `multicols` environment is not allowed. The content of each column is balanced by some algorithm written by the package author. But in the starred-version we are allow to break columns anywhere we want by presenting the `\columnbreak` command.

Comment: both `enumerate` and `proof` are list environments which allow a page break after the environment so `multicols` (which was never designed to be nested in such a place anyway) really has very little control over the page breaking after `\end{proof}` You could always put all the text that needs to stay together in a `minipage`

Comment: @SayOL I tested it before posting that comment and your example worked with `multicols` rather than `multicols*`. The manual doesn't mention it only being allowed in the starred version. However, you do need to fill in the vertical space with something like `\vfill\mbox{}\columnbreak` to avoid the column being overstretched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the first line of the proof is shorter than others due to the proof name.  You need to decide whether to put the minipage on the first line or not.  If yes, use the calculated width for the minipage.  If no, use `\strut\newline` for the first line.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newlength{\tempdima}

\begin{document}
    \begin{proof}%
      \settowidth{\tempdima}{\textit{Proof}.}%
      \rule{\dimexpr \linewidth-\tempdima-\labelsep}{1pt}\linebreak
      \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \begin{enumerate}
          \begin{multicols*}{4}
            \item First
            \columnbreak
            \item Second
            \columnbreak
            \item Third
            \columnbreak
            \item Fourth
          \end{multicols*}
        \end{enumerate}
      \end{minipage}
    \end{proof}
\noindent Can you help me to stay in the same page?
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: `\struct\newline` seems look better :)